# vb.net: Properly Show/Hide columns of radgrid

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, webforms, telerik, radgrid

I have a CheckBox that properly removes the first column in my RadGrid. The problem is when I reshow the column, it just tacks on an empty space to the end of the grid shown here:

[image: Grid problem]

CheckBox code:

```
Protected Sub ChkBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChkBox1.CheckedChanged
    If ChkBox1.Checked = True Then
        GridSurveyMain.Columns.Item(0).Visible = False
    Else
        GridSurveyMain.Columns.Item(0).Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The grid is first populated by a dropdown box that runs a sql query once a value is selected. I'm assuming that's where it's messing up? Do I need to re-run that query each time I readd the column?

edit: Just noticed that, after its readded. If I do a sort by clicking on a column it will properly fix it. Assuming that's because the grid is posting back and "refreshing"

Comment: GridSurveyMain.Rebind()

Answer (score 0):

Check the ajaxification between the CheckBox and the RadGrid:

```
AjaxManager.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSettings(ChkBox1,GridSurveyMain)
```

If necessary, ajaxify also the RadGrid on itself.